# Simple CSS Tile Layout

Tags: html, css, tiles

I need a simple way to make my layout form two tiles for content in a row.
Currently .cellleft extends to the right end so .cellright is displayed in the next row.

```
div.cellleft{
            background-color: #191a1c;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-right: 1px;
            padding-top: 1px;
            width: 43%;
        }
        div.cellright{
            background-color: #191a1c;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-right: 100px;
            margin-left: 1px;
            padding-top: 1px;
            width: 43%;
        }
```

problem pictured

[image]

Comment: Share your HTML code too.

Comment: Could you post a picture with the desired result?

Comment: the desired result is the "expected .cellright" in the picture

Comment: the html code are just divs i cant share it because of sensitive information

Comment: So you need 6 equal size tiles in 2 rows of 3 or what ?

Comment: the size does not matter. the divs grow with content. i need two rows and an infinite possibility of columns.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript to calculate/re-calculate column width for elements at run time.

Comment: So you want all your .cellleft to go left and .cellright to go right? 1 row , 2 columns?

Comment: this cant be the only solution and the window does not have to be resizable.

Comment: @gosi123 exactly

Comment: kindly update the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your `.cellleft` to go left and `.cellright` to go right, try this:

```css
.cellleft, .cellright {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.cellleft {
  background-color: red;
}

.cellright {
  background-color: blue;
}

.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<div class"row">

  <div class="cellleft">
  some contents here.. this is left cell
  </div>
  
  <div class="cellright">
  some contents here... this is right cell
  </div>

</div>

<div class="clearFloat"></div>

<div class"row">

  <div class="cellleft">
  some contents here.. this is left cell
  </div>
  
  <div class="cellright">
  some contents here... this is right cell
  </div>

</div>

<div class="clearFloat"></div>

<div class"row">

  <div class="cellleft">
  some contents here.. this is left cell
  </div>
  
  <div class="cellright">
  some contents here... this is right cell
  </div>

</div>
```

Make use of float. You can choose to float your `.cellright` to its right too.

Eg; Change in your css, `float: right` for .cellright

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that worked, if you need to extend more `row` divs, then make sure to use the clearfloat. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width:40%;
    margin:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class"row">

  <div class="box">
  some contents here.. this is left cell
  </div>

  <div class="box">
  some contents here... this is right cell
  </div>

</div>

<div class"row">

  <div class="box">
  some contents here.. this is left cell
  </div>

  <div class="box">
  some contents here... this is right cell
  </div>

</div>

<div class"row">

  <div class="box">
  some contents here.. this is left cell
  </div>

  <div class="box">
  some contents here... this is right cell
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the ideal solution for my case:

```
.cell {
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        .contentbox{
            background-color: #191a1c;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-right: 1px;
            padding-top: 1px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-right: 50px;
        }

<div class="cell">
            <div class="contentbox">
                stuff
            </div>
            <div class="contentbox">
                stuff
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="contentbox">
                stuff
            </div>
            <div class="contentbox">
                stuff
            </div>
        </div>
```